# How to improve slow performance of reactive-kafka (Scala plus Akka Streams)?

Tags: scala, akka, apache-kafka

I'm moving my project from RabbitMQ to Kafka, and am trying to understand how fast reactive-kafka will be.

I'm currently able to write about 12K/sec trivial messages/sec to Rabbit, and on read do a trivial pull from the queue through a "hello world" stream at about 4K/sec.

I moved to Kafka with reactive-streams I can write maybe 1M/sec--huge win!
But on in the same environment I can only flow about 2K/sec through the stream on read using the approach in the examples here: [DummyConsumer.scala](https://github.com/akka/reactive-kafka/blob/master/core/src/test/scala/examples/DummyConsumer.scala)

Does anyone know any tips for how I might get the read back up to levels comparable to the Rabbit approach?

Interesting:  I just tried it "directly" (accessing Kafka via the raw Java drivers vs reactive-kafka) and am getting about 22K reads, so that's pretty good.  It seams something about how I'm using reactive-kafka is slowing things waaay down.

Ok... I'm hunting this thing.  Next I tried a raw Akka stream "hello world":

```
now = System.currentTimeMillis()
count = 0
val in2 = Source(1 to num)
val g = RunnableGraph.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create() { implicit b =>
  import GraphDSL.Implicits._
  val show = Flow[Int].map{ i => count +=1; if(count==num) println(s"time 2 ($count): "+(System.currentTimeMillis() - now)); i }
  in2 ~> show ~> Sink.ignore
  ClosedShape
})
g.run()
Thread.sleep(2000)
```

This ran at a very fast 742K/sec!  So Kafka raw is plenty fast, and Akka streams is fast.  So the culprit is somewhere in either how reactive-kafka is built (or more likely) how I'm trying to use it.  Accounting for friction I should expect to see something close to raw kafka's 22K/sec.  Hmm.

Comment: Hi Greg, reactive-kafka developer here. We are finishing reactive-kafka 0.11 which should give you much more decent performance. However, older version should be more performant than merely 2K/s. Do you still have your code? I'd like to see how you use reactive-kafka.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have that code anymore.  Basically I was doing a cut'n paste from example code in the docs...nothing fancy.  I shifted and developed a project, LateKafka (in github), to create a source for Akka streams.  It is really fast--I was pulling 6-figure transactions-per-sec kafka-thru-stream for a trivial stream.   Exciting news about 0.11.  It'll be cool to try it out.

Comment: Hi Jacek, I just rebuilt my test with the new 0.11 release.  It is much faster than the M series, but I'm still unfortunately not able to reproduce the high numbers others have shown.  Note I'm just trying to get some performance--my real use case uses streams DSL, which isn't shown in the docs.  I've posted code here in another question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39617827/why-dont-i-see-high-performance-with-reactive-kafka-0-11-release

Comment: Hi Greg, We switched over to using vanilla Kafka from akka-streams saw a good performance increase too.

Answer (score 0):

Not a full answer, but try again but the recent (Sept. 2016) **[Akka Streams Kafka 0.11](http://blog.akka.io/integrations/2016/09/10/akka-stream-kafka)**

> There are significant performance improvements. We’ve done some benchmarks, and while there is still some overhead from the reactive-kafka wrapper (though keep in mind, that you also get something in return: e.g. all of the benefits coming from a nice API with asynchronous backpressure!), the overall numbers look very good and are getting better.
>
> Here’s a couple of common Kafka usage scenarios, comparing the old reactive-kafka version (M4), the current version (0.11), and equivalent functionality implemented using plain Kafka `Producers`/`Consumers` (but not taking into account, of course, connecting with any other reactive components).

[image: http://blog.akka.io/assets/kafka-bench1.png]

See more at "[Benchmarking akka-stream-kafka](https://softwaremill.com/benchmarking-akka-stream-kafka/)" from [Krzysiek Ciesielski](https://twitter.com/kpciesielski).

Comment: I'm having trouble with the new library.  Ran code like in this gist:  https://gist.github.com/gzoller/8847556ab1347b886d80cf53c3a1e867  This produced a bunch of "dead letter" errors attempting to use the batch advice from the documentation.  I also tried a variant where I only commit the head of each batch (i.e. latest offset).  This didn't give me dead letter errors but it also didn't produce a clean set of partition offsets.

Comment: @Greg Strange. You could ask a new question based on that example to see if an actual Akka Streams Kafka expert can chime in.